# I'm finished vs I finished

Tags: differences

I wonder, what's the difference between I'm finished and I finished (or even I've finished)?

**To be more specific:**

I'm given = **someone** gives something to me

I'm told = **someone** tells something to me

I'm finished = NOT **someone** makes me finish BUT  **I** have finished doing something.

Why?

Comment: Syntactically, *I **am** finished* describes your [current] state. *I [**have**] finished* describes something you did in the past. Contractions don't affect this. But semantically, there's unlikely to be any difference except in contexts where an implied "active agent" (a fatal wound or disease, for example) has brought you to a condition of impending death.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should probably just submit that as an answer, that basically covers it.

Comment: @Mike: Nah. Better to wait until someone (kudos Edwin here) finds a duplicate. Or I might have decided later to closevote for lack of research / too basic / belongs on ELL.

Comment: To elaborate bit further: 'I am' decribes your state, 'I have' describes an action. Compare "I'm told" with "I've told" - in the first instance, somebody told you, in the second, you told somebody.

Answer (score 2):

**I finished** is more emphatic.  It implies some sense of accomplishment, for example, if you feel proud of having finished an exam, or your seven-year-old has been struggling to finish his vegetables in order to get dessert.  It means that something has been completed.

**I'm finished** is more matter of fact.  "I'm finished with this book, you can read it now."  It's synonymous with "I'm done."

"I finished" is more likely to have an exclamation point.

In practice, "I've finished" sounds just like "I finished" because the V runs into the F.

Comment: why doesn't I'm finished mean "something(one) finishes me"? Like "I'm told", "I'm given".

Comment: look at my update.

Comment: I suppose the following might be an example of what you have in mind: "I crashed the company car, got my license suspended for drunk driving, and a photograph of me with the prostitute who was in the car with me was published in the newspaper.  I'm finished!"

Comment: "I was told by Peter to sign the letter" comes from "Peter told me to sign the letter."  "I was given a copy of the letter by John" comes from "John gave me a copy of the letter."  But what does "I'm finished" come from?  (Assuming it's a passive construction.)

Comment: that's right, **what does "I'm finished" come from?**

Comment: What I'm saying is that it isn't a passive construction, it's just "I am finished," which is similar to "I am tired."  Googe's definition says, "(of a person) having completed or ended an action or activity."

Comment: but why? We can't say I've smart, happy, tired, whereas we can I've finished.

Comment: @jawanam - It's unusual, but you can say *I've tired*.  Because *tire* is a verb.  Example: A teenaged family member offers to help me with some grunt work in the garden and asks for some really tough assignments.  I say, "Let me know when I've tired you out sufficiently, and then I'll give you a fun little project in the shade."

Comment: We can't say I've smart, happy, whereas we can I've finished.

Comment: Correct.  *Smart* and *happy* are not verbs.